# pgfopts: no expansion expected

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfopts

The following example

```
\begin{filecontents}{myclass.cls}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /XXX/.cd,
  foo/.store in=\foo
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/XXX}
\LoadClass{article}
\end{filecontents}
%
\newcommand\baz{FOO}
\documentclass[foo={\baz}]{myclass}
\show\foo
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

shows me

```
> \foo=macro:
->FOO.
```

I need and expect the unexpanded macro `\baz` as content of `\foo`. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\baz` not to expand in an `\edef` so:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myclass.cls}
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
  /XXX/.cd,
  foo/.store in=\foo
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/XXX}
\LoadClass{article}
\end{filecontents}
%
\protected\def\baz{FOO}
\documentclass[foo={\baz}]{myclass}
\show\foo
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
> \foo=macro:
->\baz .
l.13 \show\foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The problem with this solution: I can define `\baz` by myself  but not e.g. `\bfseries` or somthing else. The user of `myclass` should have the choice of any macros.

Comment: @rolfn define "should" :-) In an ideal world where all things worked even for new requirements added 20 years later then yes, but in this world no. `\documentclass` expands its optional argument so the only way to stop that would be to redefine `\documentclass` but you can not do that in the class as that is too late. Either you need to define it as `\protected` or to stop protection with, for example `\noexpand\bfseries`

Comment: @rolfn It is much more robust if you separate it out `\documentclass{myclass}`  then `\myclasssetup{foo=\baz}` then you have full control over expansion. this is why for example hyperref has a separate setup command even though simple hyperref options can be set in the `\usepackage` option.